# Cannot find the object 'TABLE" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, subquery, multiple-columns

I am running into an issue where I want to add a column to a table that utilizes derived tables. I eventually want to be able to populate this column using a while loop. However, when I add the column to the table I get the following error: Cannot find the object "TEST" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. I have the permissions but I am not understanding why I am being prompted with the error when the script executes without error without the " ALTER TABLE TEST ADD THEMEVALUE INT(50)" line item added.

The following is my code:

```
DECLARE @weeksPriorToConversion INT
DECLARE @periodenddate VARCHAR(50)

SET @weeksPriorToConversion = 5
SET @periodenddate = '2016-10-26'

SELECT TEST.[Casino]
FROM   (SELECT C.Casino                                       AS 'Casino',
               TML.ID                                         AS 'ID',
               TML.[Themes or Game Titles]                    AS 'Theme',
               COUNT(DISTINCT SM.[Serial Number])             AS 'Title Count',
               SUM(SMD.[StandardizedCasinoHoldv2]) / SUM(CASE
                                                           WHEN SMD.[StandardizedCasinoHoldv2] <> 0
                                                             THEN 7
                                                           ELSE NULL
                                                         END) AS 'Casino Index'
        FROM   [slot machine data] SMD
               INNER JOIN [slot machines] SM
                 ON SM .ID = SMD.[serial number]
               INNER JOIN [slot machine configurations] SMC
                 ON SM .ID = SMC.[serial number]
                    AND SMC. [Configuration Starting Date] = (SELECT MAX([Configuration Starting Date]) AS Expr1
                                                              FROM   [Slot Machine Configurations] AS SMC2
                                                              WHERE  ( [Serial Number] = SM.ID )
                                                                     AND ( [Configuration Starting Date] <= SMD.[data calendar start date] ))
               INNER JOIN [casino] C
                 ON C .ID = SMC.[casino where slot in operation]
               INNER JOIN [Themes Master List] TML
                 ON TML.ID = SMC.[Theme or Game Title]) AS TEST

ALTER TABLE TEST
  ADD THEMEVALUE INT(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `INT(50)` datatype and you can't add columns to derived tables. Derived tables just encapsulate a logical table expression in a query. They don't create any kind of actual table.

Likely you want a `#temp` table instead. You can create one with `SELECT ... INTO`.

The below creates one called `#test`. The select list includes the `THEMEVALUE` column so no need to add this separately.

```
SELECT C.Casino                                       AS [Casino],
       TML.ID                                         AS [ID],
       TML.[Themes or Game Titles]                    AS [Theme],
       COUNT(DISTINCT SM.[Serial Number])             AS [Title Count],
       SUM(SMD.[StandardizedCasinoHoldv2]) / SUM(CASE
                                                   WHEN SMD.[StandardizedCasinoHoldv2] <> 0
                                                     THEN 7
                                                   ELSE NULL
                                                 END) AS [Casino Index],
       CAST(NULL AS INT)                              AS THEMEVALUE
INTO   #test
FROM   [slot machine data] SMD
       INNER JOIN [slot machines] SM
         ON SM .ID = SMD.[serial number]
       INNER JOIN [slot machine configurations] SMC
         ON SM .ID = SMC.[serial number]
            AND SMC. [Configuration Starting Date] = (SELECT MAX([Configuration Starting Date]) AS Expr1
                                                      FROM   [Slot Machine Configurations] AS SMC2
                                                      WHERE  ( [Serial Number] = SM.ID )
                                                             AND ( [Configuration Starting Date] <= SMD.[data calendar start date] ))
       INNER JOIN [casino] C
         ON C .ID = SMC.[casino where slot in operation]
       INNER JOIN [Themes Master List] TML
         ON TML.ID = SMC.[Theme or Game Title]
```